# date comparing formula returns wrong result for one specific date value

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, formula, formulas

This might be easy to see for some of you but I struggle to find a solution. I have following formula:

```
IF(
AND(TODAY()<=E34;ISBLANK(I34));"Not started";IF(
AND(TODAY()>E34;ISBLANK(I34));"Start delayed";IF(
AND(TODAY()>I34;TODAY()<=F34;ISBLANK(J34));"In progress";IF(
AND(TODAY()>F34;ISBLANK(J34));"Completion delayed";IF(
AND(TODAY()>J34);"Done";"ERROR")
))))
```

Which compares the dates in cell E34-F34 and I34-J34 depending on the values it returns"not started","start delayed","in progress","completion delayed","done" or "Error.

E34 has date "01.06.2018"-F34 has "31.07.2018" and I34 has "01.06.2018" while J34 has "31.07.2018". Formula returns "Error" although it should return "done".

If F34 and J34 have as values 30.07.2018 instead of 31.07.2018 then formula returns "done". (It should have returned same "done" value for 31.07.2018 too)

I attach a picture of my situation. I hope someone can help[image]

Comment: Please use a tool like a [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to insert data, not images. You can paste your data from excel into the tool (there is a drop down option for this), then generate table, copy it, [edit] into your post, highlight the table and press Ctrl + K.

Comment: I suspect your are comparing text values  or at least one side of the comparison is text. Make sure you are comparing actual date values. And if J34 is 31/7/2018 that is the same as today, not greater than so wouldn't be True.

Comment: It depends on the formula that I put including "Today" Inside. As This formula is a formula that I received from someone which I work on it I can not spot the error though.

Comment: This.... AND(TODAY()>J34);"Done";"ERROR")  doesn't need an AND and only evaluates to Done if date is greater than J34.

Comment: So How should i edit my code? Can you maybe copy and edit it?

Answer (score 0):

I am a little unclear on what the real desired conditions are. In case of there being actual text rather than dates I used:

```
=IF(TODAY()>1*SUBSTITUTE(J34;".";"/");"Done";IF(
AND(TODAY()<=1*SUBSTITUTE(E34;".";"/");ISBLANK(I34));"Not started";IF(
AND(TODAY()>1*SUBSTITUTE(E34;".";"/");ISBLANK(I34));"Start delayed";IF(
AND(TODAY()>1*SUBSTITUTE(I34;".";"/");TODAY()<=1*SUBSTITUTE(F34;".";"/");ISBLANK(J34));"In progress";IF(
AND(TODAY()>1*SUBSTITUTE(F34;".";"/");ISBLANK(J34));"Completion delayed";"ERROR")
))))
```

`AND(TODAY()>J34);"Done";"ERROR")` doesn't need an `AND` and only evaluates to Done if date is greater than J34. I would move it to the front and have it as first condition tested. 31/7/2018 is not > `TODAY()`. Today is 31/07/2018 therefore is equal.

If your dates are actual dates you don't need the SUBSTITUTE parts. You can check if actual dates using the ISNUMBER function e.g. `ISNUMBER(E34)` will return True if the cell contains a date not a text string.

Without Substitute

```
=IF(TODAY()>J34;"Done";IF(
AND(TODAY()<=E34;ISBLANK(I34));"Not started";IF(
AND(TODAY()>E34;ISBLANK(I34));"Start delayed";IF(
AND(TODAY()>I34;TODAY()<=F34;ISBLANK(J34));"In progress";IF(
AND(TODAY()>F34;ISBLANK(J34));"Completion delayed";"ERROR")
))))
```

If there is still a problem I would suggest stating each of the expected test conditions and giving some input dates and expected output.

The example you gave of Error was correctly evaluated.

Comment: this does not work sadly, The problem is the "today function". Now I see my formula reads "Error" because today date is earlier/same then Actual completion date in cell J and not later then this cell

Comment: That was how it was originally. That is what I am saying. The original condidition says that is TODAY()>J34);"Done";"ERROR". Well 31/07/2018 > 31/07/2018 is False and therefore ERROR not Done. The other conditions all evaluated to False as there were no blanks. I simply re-wrote the order and it becomes more obvious.